# Preserve value between recursive method calls

Tags: java

In the below code snippet, how would one preserve the found (path) value and return it to the class who called the method?

```
public void searchFile(Path searchFrom, String match) throws IOException {
    try(DirectoryStream<Path> SearchResult = Files.newDirectoryStream(searchFrom)) {
        for(Path check : SearchResult) {
            if(!Files.isDirectory(check) && check.toString().contains(match)) {
                System.out.println(check.toString());
            } else if(Files.isDirectory(check)) {
                searchFile(check, match);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is to be able to find (file) paths recursively in a directory tree, and return these to the class who called / invoked the method.

Comment: Is it desired for there to be one or more found paths in the result?

Answer (score 0):

Return the path when found:

```
public Path searchFile(Path searchFrom, String match) throws IOException {
    try(DirectoryStream<Path> SearchResult = Files.newDirectoryStream(searchFrom)) {
        for(Path check : SearchResult) {
            if(!Files.isDirectory(check) && check.toString().contains(match)) {
                return check;
            } else if(Files.isDirectory(check)) {
                Path found=searchFile(check, match);
                if (found!=null){
                  return found;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null; // not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a third parameter and us it as the return value,
assuming that you need multiple returned values
(instead of just the first one found as demonstrated in the JP Moresmau answer).

For example

```
public class Blammy
{
    private List<Path> kapow = new LinkedList<Path>();

    public addPath(final Path newPath)
    {
        kapow.add(newPath);
    }

    public List<Path> getKapow()
    {
        return kapow;
    }
}

public void searchFile(
    final Path searchFrom,
    final String match,
    final Blammy blammy) ...
...
    // Instead of System.out.println(check.toString()); do this:
    blammy.addPath(check);
...
```